# Line style width property not being applied in QGIS 2.0.1

Tags: polyline-creation, linestring, digitizing, windows-7, qgis-2

I change the line width of my style and click apply, but the property does not seem to be applying to my line data.

Comment: These seem to be two separate questions.  Please edit your post accordingly.

Comment: Please provide a screenshot of the settings you are using. Line width works in my experience.

Comment: I have resolved it. It seems it simply was not very visible given my scale. Should I close out the question or mark it as answered and provide my own answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the line width in relation to the scale made it such that the line symbology was not showing much improvement. I fixed it by zooming closer and adjusting the line width such that it was vastly thicker.